# Ubuntu 19.04 installer hangs on keyboard layout selection

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 on a Dell Optiplex 790. I'm getting the issue where the installer hangs with an infinite spinning mouse pointer wheel when I click on "Continue" upon selecting the keyboard layout. Here are some things to note:

1. It matters not weather I select "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu"
2. same thing when booting from a USB drive, an HDD connected to SATA or a DVD
3. The USB drives where prepared with DD
4. The DVD's(2 of them) where burned with Windows 10 and K3B on Kubuntu
5. I tried to set the "nomodeset" parameter as explained on other posts but it did not work for me, unless I didn't do it properly.
6. Since Ubuntu was giving me this issue, I tried to install PopOS and I got the same problem :-S
7. Unfortunately, I don't have access to another computer to test.

This is my setup:

CPU: Intel i5-2400 (4) @ 3.400GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 580
Memory: 11961MiB
Storage: KingDian 120GB SSD

This is the first time in probably 10 years that I'm having issues installing Ubuntu. Any clues would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any additional questions as well.

Wxsabi

Comment: In these types of situations, I would normally remove every component in the PC that is attached, including the graphics card, network cards, other USB devices, nothing should be connected other than just one stick of memory and CPU and the installation medium. Give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda figured it out.

I had a PCIe to SATA expansion card. This was causing the issue. I removed it and now every thing works fine(except for the fact that I lost 6 SATA ports)

but oh well.

Comment: I'm sure you can find the driver for that after the installation completes.